# Mule 4 attributes.maskedRequestPath expected behaviour

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

The [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.7/http-documentation#HttpRequestAttributes) says:

> Path computed from masking the listenerPath and taking the difference. Note that this is only calculated when the null otherwise.

It seems this sentence is not complete so I am unsure of the expected value of maskedRequestPath.
If my request is http://localhost:8081/hello/world?abc=def
and my HTTP Listener configuration is:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="dc9" >
    <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
</http:listener-config>
```

what should be the expected output of this transform message?

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "maskedRequestPath": attributes.maskedRequestPath
}
```

I would like to know if it is "" (null) or "/".

Comment: What was the actual result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the request path that you configure at the **http:listener** level (i.e. at the flow source) and the base path at the `http:listener-config` level.

The full sentence of that documentation (as visible from the [source code](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-http-connector/blob/c53cf5a913cb6161967652226e68e9187852a47d/src/main/java/org/mule/extension/http/api/HttpRequestAttributes.java#L54))

> Path computed from masking the {@code rawRequestPath} with the {@code listenerPath} and taking the difference. Note that this
> is only calculated when the {@code listenerPath} is open (ends with a wildcard) and will be {@code null} otherwise.

So, for your request `http://localhost:8081/hello/world?abc=def` the answer depends on the path you configured at your `http:listener` (considering that you have not put anything as basepath in `http:listener-config`)

1. If it is `/hello/*` then your `maskedRequestPath` will be `/world`
2. If it is `/hello/world/*` then your `maskedRequestPath` will be `/`
3. If it is just `/hello/world` then it will be `null` as it does not end with a wildcard.

Comment: Thank you Harshank, I forgot to add my listener path, it was indeed one of the options you pointed out: /hello/world/*. So the expected behavior is it should return '/' and that's what I'm seeing. Thank you!